# How to order Laravel query builder based on first condition result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a company comparison web app that allows users to select 2 companies on different select drop-downs and compare them side by side. Everything is working well so far except for the ordering. I'd want the results of the comparison to be based on which item was queried first, rather than the default Laravel created_by field. Below is my code for the Query Builder:

```
public function compareCompanies(Request $request) {
    if ($request->has('companies') && $request->companies != null ) {
        $companies = array_filter($request->companies);

        $brands = Brand::with('categories')
        ->whereIn('brands.slug', $companies)
        ->get();
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'brands' => $brands]);        
    }
}
```

And below is my ajax for displaying the response of the POST request

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url,
        data: $("#compareForm").serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {

            if(response.success)
            {
                $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                $.each(response.brands, function(i, brand){
                    var NewRow = '';
                    NewRow += '<table class="table"><thead><tr>';
                    NewRow += '<th>' + brand.brand + '</th>';
                    NewRow += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                    NewRow += '<tr><td>'+brand.growth_score+'</td></tr>';
                    NewRow += '<tr><td>'+brand.mind_share +'</td></tr>';
                    NewRow += '<tr><td>'+brand.headquarters+'</td></tr>';
                    NewRow += '<tr><td>'+brand.revenue+'</td></tr>';
                    NewRow += '<tr><td>'+brand.no_of_employees+'</td></tr>';
                    NewRow += '</tbody></table></div>';
                    $("#companies").append(NewRow);
                })
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

The result I get is as shown on the image below:
[image: The result I get]

As you can see, the result is swapped, since Laravel orders using the value of created_at. How can I order the result respective to the order of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent allows you to order the query results by specifying a column when using the orderBy method like so:

```
 $brands = Brand::with('categories')
    ->whereIn('brands.slug', $companies)
    ->orderBy('column_name')
    ->get();
```

so if you submit the column name with your request, you can then dynamically change which column the data should be sorted by :

```
 $brands = Brand::with('categories')
    ->whereIn('brands.slug', $companies)
    ->orderBy($request->column_name)
    ->get();
```